# How to report spam of questions?

Tags: support, questions, moderation

What to do when a user is asking the same question, with different words, every few days?

First there was a series of questions asking about events of extremely low probability, and some users including myself told the user to stop spamming the SE:

- [Do miracles have a probability of zero, or are they simply extremely unlikely events?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97388/do-miracles-have-a-probability-of-zero-or-are-they-simply-extremely-unlikely-ev)
- [When exactly should we doubt that chance is at play behind a series of events? [duplicate]](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97232/when-exactly-should-we-doubt-that-chance-is-at-play-behind-a-series-of-events)
- [At which point does a meaningful coincidence call for a supernatural explanation?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95029/at-which-point-does-a-meaningful-coincidence-call-for-a-supernatural-explanation)
- [How improbable does an event have to be before we can say it didn't happen by chance?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94079/how-improbable-does-an-event-have-to-be-before-we-can-say-it-didnt-happen-by-ch)
- [Does every possible event have non-zero probability?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97136/does-every-possible-event-have-non-zero-probability)

Now it seems that the user has switched the topic and now a new series of identical, reworded questions is being asked about certainty in philosophy (already asked before in the SE, so double duplicates):

- [How does one experientially know if his analysis on any subject is correct?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97412/how-does-one-experientially-know-if-his-analysis-on-any-subject-is-correct)
- [How does one know if he is deluded?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97496/how-does-one-know-if-he-is-deluded)
- [Does philosophy rely on intuitions? If so, does this mean all of philosophy is nothing more than hunches?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97247/does-philosophy-rely-on-intuitions-if-so-does-this-mean-all-of-philosophy-is-n)

I have also now pointed the user that they are repeating questions. How to act in these cases? Is there any direct way to contact moderators?

Comment: Flag as duplicate is probably clearest way to signal this

Comment: @JosephWeissman Thank you. It seems the behaviour has stopped now.